# How to get results as array with JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

```
String sql = "SELECT name, age, gender from persons";
List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params);
```

Question: how can I get the results just as an array `List<String[]>`? As I select only 3 values from each row, I know that `result[0]` is the name, or  `results[2]` is the gender.

So I'd prefer jdbcTemplate to not return key-value maps, but just plain arrays without db column names.

Comment: Wasn't there a `queryForXXX` version that does just that? Guess not, you should use `queryForRowset` or better yet, use a `RowMapper` and map the results directly to some proper objects.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be even using this and use the query method which takes a `RowMapper` and map to your DTO directly. Looks like you are doing it afterwards.

Comment: I don't want to map to my dto. I just need the values out for further processing. So there is no need for me to introduce any type of dto or map. Thus I t hought fetching a plain array with the values would be best, but there isn't an option for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String[]> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params, String[].class)
List<String> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params, String.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Object[]> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql).stream().map(row -> row.values().toArray()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you know the columns are all String values:

```
List<String[]> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql).stream().map(row -> row.values().toArray(new String[row.size()])).collect(Collectors.toList());
```